# How to find Hidden Fields of User Control which is already in User Control in Jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

Hi iam using Jquery in ASP.Net, i have an Ajax and Json that were called for getting and setting.

My page is Voyage.aspx.

I have a User control with a ajax:Modal Popup with name Context.ascx

In Context.ascx i have other user control as per my proj requirement and the page is PortName.ascx

Here my page Voyage.aspx is calling Context.ascx  and internally its again calling PortName.ascx.

in PortName.ascx we have used Hidden fileds.

when it was with Voyage.aspx to Context.ascx I have used my code like this to find control

```
var id = $('#<%= ((HiddenField)Context.FindControl("hdnvalue")).ClientID %>').val();
```

and I got the value which is in that. Now when I try to find the HiddenFileds of the PortName.ascx it is giving error as name does not exist in current context.

How to find the hidden filed which is already in User control from my page in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Idea could be put a class and use class selector of jquery.

like

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldServerDateTime" 
             runat="server" 
             CssClass="SomeStyle" />
```

and in jQuery

```
var serverDateTime = $(".SomeStyle").val();
```

Comment: Yes i had same taught but that class which is 2nd child is not getting identified in parent page

Comment: Opps its giving Undefined value. When i try to find it in child page iam getting value., but how to return childs return value to parent and bind it to data to get saved in database??

Comment: you have only one instance of `PortName.ascx` and it contain a hidden file. So you will have only one hidden filed with the class `SomeStyle` what is the problem.

Comment: var ID = $(".ContextInfo").find("#hdnvalue").val(); This is Working., where .ContextInfo is the First child( User controls Panel class) and #hdnValue is the Second Childs HiddenFiled ID

Comment: In jquery there is not such relation. It is a simple html with controls. So when you choose class selector it does not matter where it is either on user control or user control inside user control. Until your have multiple control having the same class name.

Comment: Yes ..., Its Woring when i directly give $(#hdnvalue").val(); also..., Thanks for Help thanks a lot

Comment: your are welcome and don't forgot to mark the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ID=$('#<%=hdnvalue.ClientID%>').val()
```

Comment: This is Not direct child so its giving error as Name cant not find in current context...,

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is find client id of your hidden field in browser view source and use the same id jn jquery to get values.
eg: If you have hidden field in your user control:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnValue" runat="server" Value="Hello"/>
```

this will become something like:

```
<input id="usCon_hdnValue" type="hidden" value="Hello" name="usCon$hdnValue">
```

So, you can get values using this od:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var ID = $('#usCon_hdnValue').val();
            alert(ID);
        });
    </script>
```